# Vue.js Application Not Rendering Views on Android Emulator or Real Device, API Working Fine

Tags: android, laravel, vue.js, web

I have a Laravel + Vue.js + Inertia application that's causing an issue when trying to access the Vue.js views from both an Android emulator and a real Android device. The API endpoints are functioning correctly, but the views are not rendering as expected.

Here's what I've tried so far:

Checked CORS configuration in Laravel to ensure it allows requests from the emulator's IP.
Verified that the Vue.js application is running on my local machine's localhost and is accessible at http://192.168.1.7:80.
Confirmed that the API is working by testing it through API endpoints.
Ensured that Xdebug is configured and running and can hit breakpoints, indicating the views are being accessed.

Any suggestions or insights on what might be causing this issue or how to troubleshoot further would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!